direction of the dropdown in tom-select
Iam currently using the tom-select.js as replacenment for html select.
is it possible to get tom-select to open the dropdown upwards (above the select element) if there is not enough space to display the dropdown below the select element?
This is for example working with select2.js out of the box (but I wanted to avoid its jquery dependency ).
Thansk for help, Cornelius

Do you have a link for this tom-select.js? Version number? API docs page?

There is a position plugin for Selectize (which Tom-Select is forked from) but it doesn't seem to be implemented in TS. You could have a look at their code and try to apply some CSS to your own TS dropdown object.

Ok, found a workaround, maybe somebody is interested.
i use the onDropdownShow event to calculate which direction is best and set an appropriate css class.
new TomSelect("#myselect",{
onDropdownOpen:function(dropdown){
    let bounding = dropdown.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (bounding.bottom > (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        dropdown.classList.add('dropup');
    }
},
onDropdownClose:function(dropdown){
    dropdown.classList.remove('dropup');
},
});

and the css:
    .ts-dropdown.dropup {
    bottom: 100%;
    top: auto;
}

Best, C
